# Advice on wearable technology during MMA class to alert me of critical phone calls (on-call 24/7)

Tags: karate, mixed-martial-arts

I'm a caregiver. My phone is linked to my FIL's life alert system, but having a phone in my pocket during class is not working at all. I would like to know if anyone else has a product they use or know of someone who has luck with this type of thing. Especially need something that is durable and wont hurt me while in class. I know there's many firefighters and others who have to be on-call at all times too. Thanks for any advice:)

Comment: Is it impossible to ask the instructor that your phone be audible during class due to your profession? While not exactly ideal, most instructors should understand special/emergency cases. What parts of your body can you wear an item on? There exist apple watches and armbands which could possible be worn on ankles.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm a Taekwondo instructor. I would happily make an exception for a special case like this, put your phone on the loudest volume, somewhere at the side of the class where it's easily hearable. Even tell everyone that it's a special case for this phone to be on, if they hear it please make Danielle aware of it.

I would genuinely say just speak to your instructor. The rules are in place for a reason, but it doesn't mean that we won't make exceptions - we're human beings first, martial arts instructors second.

If not, maybe something like [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/WAYCOM-Bluetooth-Anti-Lost-Bracelet-Smart-Bracelet-Black-Black/dp/B00A4BJN94) would work (it's soft gel sort of material so reasonably safe for martial arts training).

Comment: this one https://www.amazon.co.uk/Bluetooth-Waterproof-Bracelet-Support-Monitoring/dp/B01AIGX0LQ/ref=sr_1_2?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1473235975&sr=1-2&keywords=miband is detachable from the armlet and can be put in the pocket that some MMA shorts have